# Get root, inner, and leaf nodes from a table?

Tags: mysql, binary-tree

Given a table of nodes (their Ids and their Parent Ids), how can I get all root, inner, and leaf nodes?

Here's what I have so far:

Root Nodes

```
SELECT Id, "Root" FROM NodeTable
WHERE ParentId IS NULL;
```

Inner Nodes

```
???
```

Leaf Nodes

```
SELECT N1.Id, "Leaf" FROM NodeTable N1
LEFT JOIN NodeTable N2 ON N1.Id = N2.ParentId
WHERE N2.ParentId IS NULL;
```

Is this correct? Is there a way I can do this in just one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Inner Nodes" query can be derived similarly to your "Leaf Nodes" query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT N1.Id, "Inner"
FROM NodeTable N1
JOIN NodeTable N2
  ON N2.ParentId = N1.ID
WHERE N1.ParentId IS NOT NULL;
```

This will get you all of the nodes (N1) which aren't root nodes (because they have a non-null ParentId) and which have children (N2).

And yes, you can sort of do all of this in one query, by using the `UNION` keyword.

```
SELECT Id, "Root" 
FROM NodeTable
WHERE ParentId IS NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT N1.Id, "Inner"
FROM NodeTable N1
JOIN NodeTable N2
  ON N2.ParentId = N1.ID
WHERE N1.ParentId IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT N1.Id, "Leaf" 
FROM NodeTable N1
LEFT JOIN NodeTable N2 
  ON N1.Id = N2.ParentId
WHERE N2.ParentId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! For some reason I'm when I run your Inner query on it's own, every node comes up twice. I'm pretty new to MySQL, can you help me understand why that is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Actually, that problem disappeared when I used the Union keyword. Weird!

Comment: @IanMobbs Union is a set operator. Therefore, if a row is queried twice and then union-ed with something, the row will only show up once.

Comment: @IanMobbs I have updated the query to only return Distinct rows. You got duplicates because (I suppose) it's a binary tree, and so the `JOIN` produced one row per child for each inner node.

Answer (score 13):

```
select  case 
        when p is null then concat(n, ' Root')
        when n in (select distinct p from bst) then concat(n, ' Inner')
        else concat(n, ' Leaf')
    end
from bst
order by n asc
```

Comment: You may want to elaborate on this answer. Indicate what was wrong with the original code and how you changed it. This will make it more useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

A more concise way:

```sql
SELECT 
    N, 
    IF(
        P IS NULL, 
        'Root', 
        IF(
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM BST 
                WHERE P=B.N
            ) > 0, 
           'Inner', 
           'Leaf'
       )
    ) 
FROM BST AS B 
ORDER BY N;
```

OR

```sql
SELECT 
    N, 
    IF(
        P IS NULL, 
        'Root', 
        IF(
            B.N IN (SELECT P FROM BST),
           'Inner', 
           'Leaf'
       )
    ) 
FROM BST AS B 
ORDER BY N;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select n, (case when p is null then "Root" when n in (select p from bst) then "Inner" else "Leaf" end) from BST order by n;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
SELECT distinct N1.N,
  Case
        When N1.P is null then 'Root'
        When N2.P is null then 'Leaf'
        Else 'Inner'
  End
FROM BST N1
LEFT JOIN BST N2 
  ON N1.N = N2.P
ORDER BY N1.n
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Root and Leaf Logic seems correct. Inner generally would be everything else

IF you want to perform this in 1 SQL Code Then you can try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id,
CASE WHEN Id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentId FROM NodeTable WHERE ParentId IS NOT NULL ) 
     THEN "Leaf"
      WHEN ParentId IS NULL THEN "Root"
      ELSE "Inner"
      END AS NodeType
FROM NodeTable
ORDER BY Id
```

Answer (score 1):

select n, case
when p is null then 'Root'
when n in (select p from bst) then 'Inner'
else 'Leaf'
end
from bst
order by n;

Comment: Add some example sql query with CODE Tag

Answer (score 1):

**Short and Efficient**

```
    SELECT N , CASE WHEN P is null THEN 'Root' ELSE 
   (IF (N IN (SELECT P FROM BST ), 'Inner','Leaf' ) ) END FROM BST ORDER BY N
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT(N), 'Root' FROM BST WHERE P IS NULL UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT(N), 'Leaf' FROM BST WHERE N NOT IN (SELECT 
    DISTINCT(P) FROM BST WHERE P IS NOT NULL) UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT(N), 'Inner' FROM BST WHERE N IN (SELECT 
    DISTINCT(P) FROM BST) AND P IS NOT NULL;
```

```
WHERE   
Root= Parent is null,  
leaf= when a Particular node is not a parent for any node,  
Inner= when a Particular node is a parent for any node
```

Comment: An answer without explanations does not help much.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.N,
case  
      when t.P is null then 'Root'
      when t.N in (select t1.P from  BST t1 where t1.P = t.N) then 'Inner' 
      else 'Leaf' 
end
from BST t
order by t.N
```

Comment: Only some lines of code are usually not considered useful. You should explain what the code is doing and how or why it solves the problem or answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

select n,case when p in (select n from bst ) then case when  n  in  (select p from bst) then "Inner" else "Leaf" end else "Null" end from bst order by n ;

Answer (score 0):

I believe its from this link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-1/problem

Here's what yo can do!

```
SELECT N, IF(P IS NULL, 'Root', IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BST WHERE P=B.N)>0,'Inner','Leaf')) 
FROM BST AS B 
ORDER BY N;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below is my Solution:**

```
 select N,case when level=1 then 'Root'
               when connect_by_isleaf=1 then 'Leaf'
               when level>1 and connect_by_isleaf=0 then 'Inner' 
          end
 from BST
 start with p is null
 connect by p=prior N
 order by N;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select distinct(N),x
from(
select N,P,
case when P is null and N is not null then 'Root'
when N in (Select distinct(P)from BST where P is not null) then 'Inner' 
else 'Leaf' end as x
from BST)a
order by N;
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select N, 'Root' from N1 where P is null
UNION
select N, 'Leaf'  from N1 where N not in (select P from N1 where p is not 
                                           null) 
UNION
select N , 'Inner' from N1 where N  in 
(select P from N1 where p NOT IN (select N from N1 where P is null)) 
order by n;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try..

select N,
case when B.p is NULL then 'Root'
when B.N IN(select p from BST) then 'Inner'
else 'Leaf'
End case
from BST B order by N;

Answer (score 0):

You can use exist and not exists :

select N, 'Root'
from BST where p is null
union
select N,'Leaf'
from BST a
where not exists (select  * from BST b where b.P =a.N )
union
select N,'Inner'
from BST a
where  exists (select  * from BST b where b.P =a.N  and a.P is not null)  ;

Answer (score 0):

select n
, case when p is null then 'Root'
when  n in (select distinct p from bst )  then 'Inner'
else 'Leaf' end as t

from bst order by 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT N,CASE WHEN ISNULL(P,0) = 0 THEN 'Root'
WHEN N IN (SELECT P FROM BST ) THEN 'Inner'
ELSE 'Leaf'
END NODETYPE
FROM BST
ORDER BY N
```

1. CHECK IF PARENT US NULL THEN ROOT
2. IF NODE IS IN PARENT COLUMN THEN 'INNER'
3. ELSE 'LEAF'

Answer (score 0):

```
select N, 'Root' from BST where P is null
UNION
select N, 'Leaf'  from BST where N not in (select P from BST where p is not 
                                       null) 
UNION
select N , 'Inner' from BST where N  in 
(select P from BST where p NOT IN (select N from BST where P is null)) 
order by n;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OTHER WAY:

```
SELECT 
N, 
DECODE(P, NULL, 'Root', DECODE(N, (SELECT DISTINCT S.P FROM BST S WHERE S.P=B.N),'Inner', 'Leaf')) FROM BST B
ORDER BY N;
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation. See [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select N, Case 
when P is null then 'Root' 
when N in (select P from BST) then 'Inner'
Else 'Leaf' end from BST order by N asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET(N,a.parent) and P IS NOT NULL then concat(N,' Inner')
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET(N,a.parent) = 0 and P IS NOT NULL then concat(N,' Leaf')
    WHEN FIND_IN_SET(N,a.parent) and P IS NULL then concat(N,' Root')
END)
from BST ,(SELECT group_concat(',',P) as parent from BST) as a ORDER BY N ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT N,
    CASE
    WHEN P is NULL THEN 'Root'
    WHEN N in (SELECT P FROM BST) THEN 'Inner'
    ELSE'Leaf'
    END
FROM BST ORDER BY N
```

this is my answer on MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_root') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_root
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_leaf') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_leaf
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_inner') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tbl_inner

SELECT N, 'Root' NAME INTO #tbl_root FROM BST WHERE P IS NULL

SELECT N, 'Leaf' NAME INTO #tbl_leaf FROM BST WHERE N NOT IN (SELECT P FROM BST WHERE P IS NOT NULL)

SELECT N, 'Inner' NAME INTO #tbl_inner FROM BST WHERE N IN (SELECT P FROM BST)

SELECT * FROM #tbl_root
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tbl_leaf
UNION
SELECT * FROM #tbl_inner where N NOT IN (SELECT N FROM #tbl_root)
```